# how can i fetch array from inside other array using foreach php?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, fetch

how can i fetch array from inside other array using foreach php?

i had an array like that

```
        Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [programs] => Internet Download Manager
            [version] => 6.05
            [type] => Internet
            [description] => dfsdfdsfdsfds
fds
f
sd
fds
fs

            [views] => 100
            [serial] => bbbbbb-sssss-dsdffff
yyyy-zzzz-xxxx
        )

)
```

but it could have more than array how can i fetch each one using `foreach()` function??

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking here. You can nest foreach loops - i.e. `foreach ($array as $item) { foreach($item as $subitem) { //process subitems } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is .. yes you can use foreach inside foreach.

```
foreach($arr as $k => $v){
  foreach($v as $k2=>$v2){
    foreach($v2 as $k3 => $v3){
      // go on
    }
  }
}
```

Edit:
If you want to check if the value is an array .. use `is_array($v)`

Comment: can u paste the exact error here? if the top level array contains a mix of arrays and non-array values, you can use the if(is_array($v)) to check and then if true use the foreach, otherwise handle differently.

Comment: great .. BTW welcome to stack overflow .. the way to say thank you here is by upvoting and accepting the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

foreach($something[0] as $foo => $bar) for your current example or you can look at something like http://debuggable.com/posts/xpath-on-php-arrays-set-extract:48ca6265-258c-4032-b3ff-55b84834cda3